# Syncfussion StackedColumnSeries graph with group name .But Multiple series are not working

Tags: flutter, graph, flutter-dependencies

i am using the sync fusion chart plugin with Stacked Column Series graph with group name .But Multiple series are not working there because group names do not support them. Please find me any solution.

Please find any solution

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.